# IE 10 not capturing COM events

Tags: internet-explorer, com, internet-explorer-10

I have created a dll that provides interface functions to call the methods and raise the agent events to our web application. I have javascript event handler and the dll is embedded on the page using the 'object' tag.
This works perfectly in IE 8.

In IE 10, I am able to call methods on the object, but none of the events are captured. Any help really appreciated.

Comment: Without more details on your specific implementation, it's hard to day precisely what the problem is.  Your issues may be related to Windows 8 security changes, e.g. AppContainers and the like.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn519894(v=vs.85).aspx for a very brief (and four part) introduction.  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/dn519897(v=vs.85).aspx#creating_and_opening_events may be most relevant once you've gottenthe basics.)